# Nuxt.js: meaning of "don't forget to write inside the parent component (.vue file)."

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

From Nuxt [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/):

> Nested Routes 
>   Nuxt.js lets you create nested route by using the
>   children routes of vue-router.
>
> To define the parent component of a nested route, you need to create a
>   Vue file with the same name as the directory which contain your
>   children views.
>
> **Warning: don't forget to write  inside the parent
>   component (.vue file).**

How can we translate technically the bold text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bold text is missing `write <nuxt-child/>`

So technically it means that you need to have `<nuxt-child/>` tag in parent component.

See this example https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/nested-routes/pages